# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Test Message Coming But real Published Message not come

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am using FireBase Cloud Messaging. When I published Message from Console Message coming and Notification Shown. Everything was ok. But, When I used To Come Test Message from the console, It also coming with the help of new token. But, After that When I publish real message (not Test), now the published message not come, only coming the test message. So is there any problem in my codes?

My codes as follows :

```
public class FirebaseCloudNotification extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}

private  static  final String TAG = "FirebaseMessaging";
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.alquran.tafhimul_quran.FireBaseChannelId";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null)
   if( remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()!=null&& remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()!=null)
       showNotificationCompat(this, _StartActivitySuraList.class,remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction() ,  remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), 555 );


}



public void showNotificationCompat(final Context context, Class<?> cls,String clickAction, String title, String content, final int REQUEST_CODE)
    {



    Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
    String t =title+"#"+content;
    intent.putExtra("fireBaseNotification", t);
    intent.setAction("From.Firebase.Notification");
    intent.setData((Uri.parse("####://"+t)));


   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, new Random().nextInt() /* Request code */, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    String channelId = CHANNEL_ID;
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.inapp4)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(3 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Firebase Cloud Messaging Console I have to remove all test token, (as it is it removed my test device). Then Everything is fine.

For removing all test token you have to click on Test Message (blue ) Button.